# line integral of 3D vector field

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a 3D vector field $\vec v(x,y,z)=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and I want to compute 
$$\int_C \vec{v}\cdot \vec n\, dS$$
where $C$ is the unit circle $C\equiv\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\, x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $\vec n$ is the outward unit normal to $C$. I am confuse as to how to approach this since the integral is for a a 3D vector field not over a surface but over a curve. Should I set $v_3=0$ and/or the third component of the normal vector zero as well, i.e., if\,  $\vec n=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then set $v_3=0$.?

Answer (score 1):

A curve in space *has* no outward unit normal $n$. Where you've written "$v \cdot n\, dS$", perhaps you mean "$v\cdot d\mathbf{s}$", denoting the "vector line element"? If so, to calculate the line integral, it suffices to parametrize your curve (here, the circle) by a piecewise $C^{1}$ map $\gamma$ defined on some interval $[a, b]$ (e.g., $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$), so that
$$
\int_{C} v \cdot d\mathbf{s}
  = \int_{a}^{b} v\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr) \cdot \gamma'(t)\, dt.
$$
The right-hand side is an ordinary, one-variable integral.